# jQuery.animate() and animate() callback in IE7 don't work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have this Code:

```
var items = jQuery('#main .imgteaser .txtwrap');

 items.css("opacity","0.8");

 items.mouseenter(function(){
  alert('enter');
  jQuery(this).animate({ 
   bottom: "0",
   opacity: 1,
   border: "1px solid #a6a6a6"
  }, 500, function(){alert('enter animation ready');});
  jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
 });

 items.mouseleave(function(){
  alert('leave');
  jQuery(this).animate({
   bottom: "-60",
   opacity: 0.8,
   border: "1px solid #fff"
  }, 500, function(){alert('leave animation ready');});
  jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
 });
```

In Firefox it works good, but in the IE7 the leave jQuery animation don't work and the callback function don't work too.

Comment: Is this the actual code ? (*copy/pasted ?*)  If so, make sure you comment out the `console.log` .. Also, if you can put something online (*or show the HTML as well*) it would help a lot.

Comment: I have change the console.log to alert.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `}` after the alert in the **leave** function (*callback*).

Comment: Here is a Demo (a part): http://pplum.de/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery simply fails to animate the border in IE: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5001

I once found plugin that animate background color, but couldn't find now any plugin that "fix" animation for borders.

One way around is to place the element inside placeholder with padding of `1px` then animate the background of that whole placeholder using this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

With the plugin in place, just call `.animate()` as usual passing the new background color.

Answer (score 1):

Check that there is no `,` after the last entry of the animate array! FF can handle this, IE not.

**Example**

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    alert('finished!!!');
  } //                      <-- NO COMMA HERE!!!
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 items.mouseenter(function(){
  alert('enter');
  jQuery(this).animate({ 
   bottom: "0",
   opacity: 1,
   border: "1px solid #a6a6a6"
  }, 500, function(){alert('enter animation ready');); //<-- you are missing the closing bracket here
  jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
 });
```

Fix:

```
 items.mouseenter(function(){
  alert('enter');
  jQuery(this).animate({ 
   bottom: "0",
   opacity: 1,
   border: "1px solid #a6a6a6"
  }, 500, function(){alert('enter animation ready');});
  jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
 });
```

Comment: Yes i have already see this missing closing bracket. But in the demo: http://pplum.de/demo.html there is the closing bracket and it dont work in IE7.